# Cefsharp in WPF rendering only when resized

Tags: wpf, cefsharp

We have a WPF application with CefSharp 79.1.360.0.
On one specific computer, CefSharp does not render unless the application is resized.
On the DevTools we see that the call to load the new page are made and are successfull.

Our application is installed on dozens of computer with various configuration but the problem occurs on only one of our customer device.
We know the customer has 3 screens with 2 of them being duplicated and has a dpi of 150% on the main screen. However we do not reproduce whe this configuration. And the issue is still present with a DPI of 100%.

All of the rendering issue I found mention the DPI but it does not seem to be the problem here.

Comment: Is it an Intel 11th Gen iris graphics cards? https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/3817

Comment: It is indeed an intel 11th iris graphics cards. Thanks for the link. If you create an answer with those info I will accept it

Answer (score 0):

For Intel 11th Core Iris Xe Integration graphic cards there is a known issue that currently we are waiting on Intel to release an updated driver. Subscribe to https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/3817 on GitHub for updates.

In the meantime the two workarounds are:

- Use software only rendering in WPF (RenderMode.SoftwareOnly)
- Switch to using [CefSharp.Wpf.HwndHost](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.Wpf.HwndHost/) which is a HwndHost based implementation, similar to using the WinForms version in WPF using a WindowsFormsHost. Unlike the WinForms version supports binding. Airspace issues apply.

Comment: Intel reportedly have an updated driver available for download https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000058136/graphics/graphics-for-11th-generation-intel-processors.html