# CefSharp WPF not rendering until resize in a specific PC

Tags: wpf, cefsharp

I just tried to copy my wpf app repository to another PC and start to test my app.
But in my another pc, cefsharp render very slowly or not render until resize the app window size.
I run my app which has similar Specifications, it work normaly.
Click events are work, but changed screen is not refreshed until resize my wpf app.
Please help me!! I searched every weeks for this problem, but I can't get any answer about my problem.

Comment: Likely a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/67884746/4583726

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Finally! I solved problem. Thank you again.